# div scrollbar disappears when placed in showmodaldialog

Tags: javascript

i have an aspx page where all the content is placed in a div which is having property overflow:auto; and im trying to dispaly the aspx page inside a showmodalDialog(which is resizeable)

I made the height and width of div almost equal to showmodalDialog height and width...
and the scrollbar appears properly...but when i resize the ShowmodalDialog the scrollbar Disappears...

Please let me know how can i make the div exactly fit in ShowModalDialog eventhough i resize or maximize the Showmodaldialog ...so that even Scrollbar(in div) appears everytime...
i do not want to enable scroll for showmodaldialog...